# How to query posts with certain custom meta data, and output Post data

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I've been working on modifying the Thesography plugin to include the Google Maps API. So far I've had success doing so.

I'm looking to take this one step further and have 1 large Google Map that would display all of my images on 1 map. Then when you hover over a marker, an image thumbnail comes up with the post title. I know the requirements for the Google Maps API to make this possible, but am struggling with trying to get the data out of MySQL.

I'm looking for some coding help that'll help me extract the following information from a post, IF it has "latlng_readable" in the post_metadata. For the Google Map, I'd like to be able to grab the post title, the post image URL and the "latlng_readable" meta coordinates for the marker pin.

This way I can put this into the Google Maps API so that in the popup box for my marker is a little thumbnail of the image, as well as the title of that image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying using `WP_Query()` using [the `meta_query` arguments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Something like this:

```
<?php
$geotag_post_query_args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'latlng_readable'
);

$geotagged_posts = new WP_Query( $geotag_post_query_args );
?>
```

Now, `$geotagged_posts` is a query object, that should include all Posts that have the `latlng_readable` meta field. You can extract the `$post` data from this object the same as any other query object.

Comment: I integrated this into the geotagging plugin I've been modifying, and used print_r to see what the array was holding. It didn't look like anything useful. At the beginning was "WP_Query Object ( [query_vars] => Array ( [meta_key] => latlng_readable [error]" < snip>. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What array are you using `print_r()` on, the *arguments* array? The data returned by `WP_Query()` is an *object*, not an *array*.

Comment: That output was from print_r($geotagged_posts);, however when I changed it to print_r($geotag_post_query_args);, I got: NotAvailableArray ( [meta_key] => latlng_readable ).

Comment: Try `var_dump( '$geotagged_posts );`.

Comment: My newbieness is showing through I guess. That returned this: array(1) { ["meta_key"]=> string(15) "latlng_readable" }

Comment: Okay, something's not right here. That's returning `$geotag_post_query_args`, *not* the output from `new WP_Query( $geotag_post_query_args )`. Note how that's simply an array, that contains your query argument?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2436/discussion-between-pat-and-chip-bennett)